# What's the difference between SSIS Package Configuration connection string and the other properties?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

When I create an SSIS Package Configuration settings, I have the option to export the connection managers and their properties. If I export all the settings, does that mean if I change the server on the "ConnectionString" I have to change it in the "InitialCatalog"? What happens if the ConnectionString property contains a different InitialCatalog than the "InitialCatalog" Property? Which one will SSIS use when I run the package?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

conncetion string is the collection of 
server name,
initial catalog(database name), 
username, 
password

you need to specify these and can change connection and if you want to change only single parameter then go with individual property.

If you had specified different values for a same property in same level then it will throws error.

Answer (score 0):

you may not need to export ConnectionString property.
You can work with Initial Catalog and ServerName while using Native Security Mode.

And for that instance, where you want to keep Value of ConnectionString and Initial Catalog differently in separate variables that will throw an error.

The ConnectionString, Initail Catalog, ServerName, UserName and Password are given separately for different kind of ETL architecture and design.

When I create an SSIS Package Configuration settings, I have the option to export the connection managers and their properties. If I export all the settings, does that mean if I change the server on the "ConnectionString" I have to change it in the "InitialCatalog"? What happens if the ConnectionString property contains a different InitialCatalog than the "InitialCatalog" Property? Which one will SSIS use when I run the package?